# Миграция в ClearDB MySQL

Tags: mysql, heroku

Имеется БД MySQL, которую надо импортировать в heroku, но heroku работает только с postgres. Однако есть плагин ClearDB MySQL. Попробовал сделать импорт существующей БД вот так:

`create cleardb:ignite --fork=mysql://username:password@127.0.0.1:3306/geomagnetic -a diplomaproject2019`

Проблема в том, что не происходит миграции БД MySQL. Вместо этого создается пустая БД и всё. Как осуществить миграцию БД в ClearDB MySQL?

Comment: Операция - одноразовая. Так что разумнее делать не чтобы просто, а чтобы медленно и надёжно. Т.е. аккуратно сперва переместить структуру (экспорт, ручная рихтовка, загрузка), потом данные (через CSV).

Comment: @Akina как это сделать?

Comment: Что значит как? Heroku в сторону, и работаете только с MySQL и PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Я импортировал существующую БД в Cleardb, следующим образом:

1)Для начала сделал дамп БД MySQL ([здесь](https://youtu.be/-Ccu7GYcgmE) показано как создать дамп БД и как восстановить БД из дампа).

2)Потом используя CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL, с помощью mysql workbench подключился к уже созданной БД в Cleardb ([здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBe9sf1aYLA) показано как это делать)

3)Восстановил из дампа таблицы в БД, которая создана в ClearDB. При восстановлении данных из дампа могут возникнуть проблемы с кодировкой [здесь](https://sysadmin.ru/articles/ispravlyaem-oshibku-1273-unknown-collation-utf8mb4_unicode_ci) и [здесь](https://sysadmin.ru/articles/ispravlyaem-oshibku-1115-unknown-character-set-utf8mb4) сказано как их решить (я использовал "НЕ Правильный способ")